# Add multiple predicates to isearch-filter-predicate

Tags: replace, isearch, query-replace, nadvice, isearch-filter-predicate

I wrote a set of predicates to filter matches in my `ìsearch-*` and `query-replace*` routines. I also wrote a macro to bind the `isearch-filter-predicate` variable to multiple predicates:

```el
(defmacro with-ifp-predicates (PREDICATES &rest body)
  (declare (indent 1))
  `(let ((isearch-filter-predicate isearch-filter-predicate))
     (mapcar (lambda (x)
               (add-function :before-while isearch-filter-predicate x))
             ,PREDICATES)
     ,@body))
```

I use it in my code in this way:

```el
(with-ifp-predicates '(skip-maths skip-comments)
  (query-replace "foo" "bar" nil (point-min) (point-max)))
```

I tested it and it seems to work but if I enter `recursive-edit` (`C-r`) and look at the value (`C-h v`) of the `isearch-filter-predicate` variable, I get this:

[image]

Is it normal? Is it caused by the `:before-while`? I chose it because I need a match to be skipped if just one of the predicats is satisfied.

Comment: Yes, it's normal.  `add-function` generates those objects (which are byte-compiled-functions).  In Emacs-26, you should see it displayed in a slightly more user-friendly way which would make it clear that it's an advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's normal. The code is byte-compiled on the fly.  See `nadvice.el` (`advice-p`, for example).

Because of this it can help to give a piece of advice a user-friendly name, which can kind of describe it.

---

FWIW, you might want to take a look at the [dynamic Isearch filtering](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DynamicIsearchFiltering) available with [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus). It gives you easy ways to add, combine, and remove Isearch filter predicates, either interactively or with code. I think it gives you a generalization of what you're doing now.

With respect to describing (at least naming) Isearch filter predicates:

- You can name each predicate you activate (add) dynamically.
- The names of the active predicates, and their order, can be shown in the Isearch prompt, so you can tell what filtering is being used.
- You can also name the current suite of filter predicates, creating a named predicate that does the same thing. You can use that name to reuse the suite later or to easily remove it as the current predicate. See function `isearch-defun-filter-predicate`.

---

BTW - I'm glad to see someone taking an interest in using Isearch filtering, and in a flexible way.  In vanilla Emacs it is so far used rarely, and only with hard-coded filters for a few particular contexts.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will study them carefully. This tool is proving to be very powerful in my work as a LaTeX typesetter, eliminating false positives from my `query-replace` routines and saving me a lot of time and mental energy.

Comment: Cool. Really glad to see people using Isearch filtering.